# URL.openStream very slow

Tags: java, android, url, upload, inputstream

I'm downloading a picture on a android device from a SQL database; Everything works well, except that opening the Stream takes very long time (even if there is no picture to download). It takes approx 5 sec's before the actual download starts. Here is my code snippet:

```
URL url = new URL(sUrl[0]);
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
connection.connect();

int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();

//input = connection.getInputStream();
InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());


File file = new File(
        Environment
                .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
        "MyCameraApp" + "/testpic.jpg");
OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file);
byte data[] = new byte[1024];

//---blabla progressbar update etc..
```

The line `InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());` gives the problem. Any idea's on how to speed things up?

Comment: Are you SURE that the delay happens in that statement?  I'd have expected it to occur in the `connect()` call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use this code to get a bitmap from a url. :)

```
Bitmap bitmap = null;
    URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)imageUrl.openConnection();
    conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
    conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
    InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);

try
{
   byte[] bytes=new byte[1024];
   for(;;)
   {
      int count=is.read(bytes, 0, 1024);
      if(count==-1)
         break;
      os.write(bytes, 0, count);
    }
 }
 catch(Exception ex){}
os.close();
bitmap = decodeFile(f);
```

Comment: Well it actually does, it about 2-3 seconds faster.. thanks! Maybe the use of HTTPURLConnection speeds things up..

Comment: @user1337210 No. You are already using it. The only difference here is the typecast. There is nohing here that answers the question.

Answer (score 4):

That's the point at which the actual TCP connection is created. It's a network problem, not a coding problem. Nothing you can do in the code to fix it.

Comment: Actually, the TCP connection is made a statement or two earlier ... because he'd getting the content length.  But you are probably right that this is just network delay, and there's no fix for this in the Java client code.

Comment: @StephenC Yep. In that case it must be the `getContentLength()` that is taking the time.

Answer (score -1):

You're calling `url.openStream()` when creating the `InputStream`, but prior to that you're creating a new connection and calling `connection.connect()`.

**From the android JavaDoc:** `openStream()` is "Equivalent to `openConnection().getInputStream(types)`"

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URL.html#openStream()

In summary I think you should call `connection.getInputStream()` when initialising the `InputStream`.

Comment: Both events happen anyway. The connect is implicit if you don't do it explicitly. See the Javadoc.